# How to encode or filter _GET and get ridd of %20

Tags: php, html

I have a php script that catches a post response from a server

This is how i catch the variables

```
$id = $_GET["variable1"];
$name = $_GET["variable2"];
$type = $_GET["variable3"];
```

I get this line from the server

```
http://www.example.com/myscript.php?variable1=667,%20&variable2=john,%20&variable3=shoes
```

How am i gonna grab the right vars here? I dont want the ",%20"
The correct in this example should be something like this.

```
http://example.com/myscript.php?variable1=667&variable2=john&variable3=shoes

$id = 667
$name = john
$type = shoes
```

My issue is that i cannot control what the server sends me in its string so i need to filterout the ,%20 or is there some another way so i can get them into my vars.

Comment: theres a function just for that in the manual

Comment: So the first question is whay are you getting this request to your server in a format you are not expecting?  Why can you ont resolve this problem. If, as you say, you have no control over this, you have a number of options depending on whether this behavior is predictable (i.e. does it ALWAYS happen for EVERY parameter) or not.

Comment: Adding to Dagon: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%20` is a space. You can just `urldecode()` the GET parameters and remove trailing `,%20`s, or just read and alter the PHP predefined `$_GET` array, which is urldecoded by default.

```
// Let's just make a copy of $_GET
$params = $_GET;
// Now let's walk over the array.
foreach ($params as $key => $val) {
    // We need to get rid of the last two characters from $val
    // (comma, space). So we just overwrite the value of $val
    // with 2 characters cut off from the string.
    $params[$key] = substr($val, 0, strlen($val) - 2);
}
```

Comment: Notes ¶

Warning
The superglobals $_GET and $_REQUEST are already decoded. Using urldecode() on an element in $_GET or $_REQUEST could have unexpected and dangerous results. http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: @DOCASAREL Ah, sorry, I forgot. Then `urldecode()` is unnecessary.

Comment: Plus I'm getting curious about *why* using `urldecode()` on an already decoded `$_GET` mapping would be dangerous. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use urldecode function. It'll remove those special characters from your URL.

```
$new_url = urldecode("http://www.example.com/myscript.php?variable1=667,%20&variable2=john,%20&variable3=shoes");
```

You can also separate your parameters,

```
foreach (explode('&', "http://www.example.com/myscript.php?variable1=667,%20&variable2=john,%20&variable3=shoes") as $chunk) {
   $param = explode("=", $chunk);
   if ($param) {
      printf("Value for parameter \"%s\" is \"%s\"<br/>\n", urldecode($param[0]), urldecode($param[1]));
   }
}
```